# how to create custom facebook dialog box for "POST TO WALL"

Tags: android, facebook

private final class ScoredialogListener implements DialogListener
        {

```
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String message = "This is Customize Post this to my wall";
              Bundle params = new Bundle();             
              params.putString("message", message);
              mFacebook.dialog(SampleApp.this, "stream.publish", new ScoreDialogListener());
              mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST", new ScoreReqestListener(),null);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the customize facebook dialog box to post a message but every time i am getting default dialog box.

So how to make custom dialog box by using facebook-android api.

Thanks in advance,